# Unhandled exception: Corrupted heap and access violation reading memory location

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to write a multithreading program for a hw assignment.  So far, all I've got in my program is some code to read a set of binary data files (provided for the assignment), and read the contents of those files into a 2D data array. The program builds without any errors, but when I run it, it exits after reading the names of the DAT files from a specified metadata file.  I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong, and any help will be appreciated!

This is the error I receive:

"Unhandled exception at 0x773a5c0c (ntdll.dll) in MultiThreading.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted."

Followed by:

"Unhandled exception at 0x7730d1ed (ntdll.dll) in MultiThreading.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000001e."

This is my code, and I'm positive there's an error in there somewhere, but I'm new to C++ programming and I can't find it :-/

```
// MultiThreading.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

//include the custom header file
//#include <Engine.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;


void ReadData(char * filename, int * nVals, float ** dataVals);
int ReadMeta(char * metaFile, int * nThreads, int * nFiles, string ** filenames);


void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //set default # of threads in case no user input is provided
    int nThreads = 12;

    //assign default metainfo file in case no user input is provided
    char metaFile[200] = "DataFiles\\MetaInfo.txt";

    //check for console user input for threads and metainfo file, if available
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        nThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

        if (argc > 2)
        {
            strcpy_s(metaFile, argv[2]);
        }
    }

    //initialize # of files and string to hold filenames
    int nFiles = 0;
    string * filenames = NULL;

    //read metainfo to get # of data files and file names
    //Call ReadMeta(metaFile, &nThreads, &nFiles, &filenames);

    //check for errors in reading metainfo
    if (ReadMeta(metaFile, &nThreads, &nFiles, &filenames) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error reading data files and/or requesting threads."
            << "\nOperation aborted!\n\n";
    }


    //read file data into multiple arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < nFiles; i++)
    {
        cout << "Reading contents of data file " << filenames[i];
        int nVals = NULL;
        float * dataArray = NULL;

        //convert string to char for filename to pass to function
        char * binFile = (char*)filenames[i].c_str();

        //read files and write to dataArray
        ReadData(binFile, &nVals, &dataArray);
    }

    //release memory
    if (filenames) delete[] filenames;
    filenames = NULL;

    system("pause");
}

int ReadMeta(char * metaFile, int * nThreads, int * nFiles, string ** filenames)
{
    ifstream inputFile(metaFile);

    //check for error locating metainfo file
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Target file " << metaFile << " was not found.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //assign # of files to *nFiles
    inputFile >> (*nFiles);

    //check if data files are listed in metainfo file
    if (*nFiles < 1)
    {
        cout << "No data files are provided!\n";
        inputFile.close();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (*nFiles < 2)
    {
        cout << "NOTE: Only ONE data file is available.\n\n";
    }
    //print number of data files to screen
    else
    {
        cout << *nFiles << " data files are available.\n\n";
    }

    //check for # of threads being requested and set to default value if reqd
    if ((*nThreads <= 0) || (*nThreads > *nFiles))
    {
        cout << "WARNING: Invalid number of threads requested.\n"
            << "Number of threads truncated to valid range 2 - " << *nFiles
            << "\nDefault value is 2 threads.";

        *nThreads = 2;
    }

    //print # of data files and threads to screen
    cout << *nFiles << " files are available.\n"
        << *nThreads << " threads have been requested.\n"
        << "Each file is assigned to a separate thread.\n";

    //adjust number of threads
    if (*nThreads > *nFiles)
    {
        *nThreads = *nFiles;
        cout << "Fewer threads will be created due to insufficient data files." 
            << "That is, only " << *nThreads << " threads will be created.\n\n";
    }
    else if (*nThreads < *nFiles)
    {
        *nFiles = *nThreads;
        cout << "Fewer files will be used to meet the thread requirements."
            << "That is, only " << *nFiles << " files will be used for " 
            << *nThreads << " threads.\n\n";
    }

    //assign file names to *filenames
    *filenames = new string[*nFiles];
    for (int i = 1; i <= (*nFiles); i++)
    {
        inputFile >> (*filenames)[i];
        cout << "\nData file #" << i << ": " << (*filenames)[i].c_str() ;
    }

    //close metainfo file
    inputFile.close();



    cout << endl << endl;
    return 1;
}

void ReadData(char * filename, int * nVals, float ** dataVals)
{
    //open the file "filename" passed to the function
    FILE * thisFile;
    fopen_s(&thisFile, filename, "rb");

    //read the number of values contained in the file
    fread(nVals, sizeof(int), 1, thisFile);

    //create an exact sized array to hold the values contained in the file
    *dataVals = new float[*nVals];

    //read values from file to array
    fread(*dataVals, sizeof(float), *nVals, thisFile);

    //close the file
    fclose(thisFile);

}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 on a Windows 10 x64 system. The program is configured for Win32.

Absolutely ANY help or any directions that can help me fix this will be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: heap corruptions are difficult to debug without enabling gflags. What you need to do is: 1.) build your program with optimizations disabled so that all symbols are built into application 2.) enable gflags (enable page heap) on the machine for this specific application 3.) run your program. When access violation occurs, the resulting stack will give you more information on where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Arrays start from 0: this loop looks funny:

`*filenames = new string[*nFiles];
    for (int i = 1; i <= (*nFiles); i++)
    { ... }`

Comment: Also replace your arrays of `std::string` with `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful pointers!  I'm working on writing the rest of the program  Fixing the start of the loop to 0 fixed the exception, but I'm not sure I'm writing the data file info to dataArray correctly either.  That's what I'm going to try and fix now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*filenames = new string[*nFiles];
for (int i = 1; i <= (*nFiles); i++)
{
    inputFile >> (*filenames)[i];
    cout << "\nData file #" << i << ": " << (*filenames)[i].c_str() ;
}
```

Arrays in C++ start with index of 0. An array `filename` containing five elements contains elements `filename[0]` through `filename[4]`.

In this case, you would allocate an array of five strings, but instead of initializing `filename[0]` through `filename[4]`, you will attempt to initialize `filename[1]` through `filename[5]`.

Since `filename[5]` does not exist, this result in undefined behavior. A runtime crash that you've observed is one of the likely results from this undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you!  I'd send you hugs, but instead I send you gratitude. That fixed the exception.